# An early 2000s PC game in which you had to kill Smurfs and Care Bears

Tags: story-identification, video-games

This was some kind of weird PC game which was very typical from the early 2000s.

From what little I remember, the game started out in a level in which you shot [Gargamel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gargamel) dead, after which he blew off into pieces, before proceeding forwards and killing the [Smurfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Smurfs) that are charging towards you. The character you control is as small as the Smurfs, and you could either play alone or cooperatively (with another player on the same keyboard).

In another level I remember, we had to fight against [Care Bears](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Care_Bears), who were about the same size as the Smurfs from the first level. Some of them attacked you by getting into range and using some kind of rainbow attack.

When you ran out of health, I think your character would vanish and his hat would fall to the ground.

Comment: Reminds me of Diablo III's unicorn levels... some fans griped that they saw a rainbow in some set-piece art near a waterfall, so devs created a whole level full of rainbows, unicorns, "cuddle bears" and other cute tropes... and all of them are trying to kill you!

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Never played it personally, but I still vividly remember seeing an unicorn getting cut in two and seeing the two pieces fall apart, while looking at a relative playing it. Or was it a little pony parody?

Comment: yeah that was it. Being Diablo, they didn't spare the gore.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Blip & Blop : Balls of Steel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6dOeeD4q2P0) ?

> Always wanted to shoot and kill your favorite game and childhood tv
> characters such as Mario, The Smurfs, Pokemon, Lara Croft or even some
> of those cute care bears? Yes? This Windows game is for you!
>
> Blip & Blop is basically a free arcade oriented game, a 2D shoot game
> like Gryzor and Metal Slug. The funny part of this game is that you
> have to deal with some bad guys who bear a striking resemblance with
> some well-known characters.
>
> Be ready to face evil Snuffs, mighty Scare bears, vicious Snorkis and
> the terrifying Dorkemons. Prepare for a fight with some of the most
> feared foes of the video game industry.

Comment: Very likely. Damn, that was fast.

Comment: I googled "PC game in which you had to kill Smurfs and Care Bears".

Comment: There's a rainbow attack at the 6:59 mark in the linked video that I pretty much recognise, so I can confirm it's the correct one (just waiting to be able to accept). Strangely enough, the Gargamel part doesn't seem to fit what I remember though.